# What is the current status or resolution of Greisen–Zatsepin–Kuzmin (GZK) cosmic-ray paradox?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, astrophysics, cosmic-rays

The Greisen–Zatsepin–Kuzmin limit (GZK limit) is a theoretical upper limit on the energy of cosmic ray protons traveling from other galaxies through the intergalactic medium to our galaxy.

A number of observations have been made by the largest cosmic-ray experiments that appeared to show cosmic rays with energies above this limit (called extreme-energy cosmic rays, or EECRs). The observation of these particles was the so-called

> [GZK paradox or cosmic-ray paradox.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit). It was considered to be an open problem in physics.

These observations appear to contradict the predictions of special relativity and particle physics as they are presently understood. However, there are a number of possible explanations for these observations that may resolve this inconsistency.

Some possible old resolutions:

- The observed EECR particles can be heavier nuclei instead of protons.
- The cosmic rays could have local sources within the GZK horizon (although it is unclear what these sources could be). [Mirror matter?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter)
- The observations could be due to an instrument error or an incorrect interpretation of the experiment, especially wrong energy assignment.

**Question: What is the current status or resolution of Greisen–Zatsepin–Kuzmin cosmic-ray paradox?**

Comment: "Paradox" is a self-serving inflammatory term. There is also [recent serious work](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fspas.2019.00023/full) on the subject.

Comment: Isn't the GZK cutoff related to a probability of pion production from the interaction of a high energy proton with the microwave background?  If so, I am guessing the probability of producing a pion and lower energy proton or neutron is not unity, right?  So even if cosmic rays above this limit are protons, I assume there's a finite probability of that occurring and not strictly violating the GZK cutoff, correct?  Besides, not all cosmic rays must be protons, so why is this a contradiction?